# find dynamically created control and hide it

Tags: c#, winforms

Again, I was creating buttons dynamically based on this [post](http://bitvector.net/?p=41) and now I need to hide it accordingly. How do I find and hide the buttons. This is new to me because I'm used to drag/drop and do stuff with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var button = (from b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
              where b.Name == nameOfButton).First();

button.Hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using my example from your previous question, I added a "name" property:

```
int lastX = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  Button b = new Button();
  b.Name = "button" + i.ToString();
  b.Location = new Point(lastX, 0);
  this.Controls.Add(b);
  lastX += b.Width;
}
```

Now you can access it by name:

```
if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("button1"))
  this.Controls["button1"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: I forgot `Controls` also takes the name as the index; my WinForms is rusty.

Comment: @LarsTech -- do you have any idea why when I hide the button, it doesnt shift over? for example i want: btn1, btn2, btn3 --> btn1, btn3 ... instead i get btn1, , btn3 ... I want btn3 to shift to where btn2 is.

Comment: @Calvin You explicitly set the location of your buttons.  There isn't any default code used by the form to move them over.  For that, you should consider using a ToolStrip control with ToolStripButtons or put your buttons inside a FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: @LarsTech -- so is there a way to incorporate the dynamic buttons inside a flowlayoutpanel? if so, can you give me some pointer?

Comment: @Calvin You should probably try playing with one and if you get stuck, feel free to post a new question about it.  In general, place a FlowLayoutPanel on the form and then you just add your buttons to the panel, for example: `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button());`  You don't set the location of controls in the panel since it handles the "flowing" part.

Answer (score 0):

you must know the name of your control. And then use this:

```
foreach(Control control in Controls){
  if (control.Name == "your control name"){
      control.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

if your controls are in a panel named mypanel, for example, you must write `foreach(Control control in mypanel.Controls)`
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your dynamically created controls in a `Dictionary<string, ControlType>`, you can find them pretty easily and efficiently.  The key would be your control name, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If your form contains panels etc. containers, you should do a recursive search:

```
void SetVisible(Control c)
{
    if (control.Name == "your control name") 
          control.Visible = false; 

    foreach(Control control in c.Controls){       
      SetVisible(control);       
    }

}
```

And then somewhere call:

```
SetVisible(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Really old question, but the accepted answer didn't work for me because my controls were nested (children of another control).

The Controls.Find method worked for me with passing in 'true' for the second parameter which tells it to search children:

```
        Control c = panelControls.Controls.Find("MyControlName", true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (c != null && c is ComboBox) {
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)c;
            cmb.Hide();
        }
```

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find